# Joomla main menu not showing up

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Seriously I'm going nuts here.

I wanted to transfer a site I have to Joomla. As I'm recreating that site by writing my own template I just don't manage to get this main menu to show up on the page.

I'm experienced developing components but fairly new in developing templates.
Here are a few screenshots to show my current situation:

The body of my index.php.

```
<body>

    <jdoc:include type="module" name="mainmenu" title="Main Menu"/>
    <jdoc:include type="component" />

</body>
```

[The menus manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iprHH.jpg)

[The modules manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pZsn.jpg)

- Creating a menu, check.
- Creating a menu module, check.
- Assigning the menu to the menu module, check.
- Assigning it a position, check.
- including that position in my index.php, check.

What is wrong here?!

Edit:
Maybe its interesting for you to know that this is a new and almost default Joomla 3.6 installation. Other than installing my template, there have no fancy configurations been made.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `type="modules"` not `type="module"`.

Also, make sure it is referenced in your templateDetails.xml file.

Comment: Oh no, say this isn't true.......I spent 2 days on this.